# Locked black screen after upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, thinkpad

I have just done the upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10. After restarting i get a black screen, with the cursor blanking, but i cant type anything on the screen. I am using Think-pad T400. How should i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> during boot and get to the terminal and update everything:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```